# How to create a pandas series from two series based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

How should I go about creating Series C from Series A and B?
Where:

```py
Series A    Series B
1           Nan
1           Nan
Nan         1
```

and

```py
Series C
1
1
1
```

In my case the two series are complementary with no overlaps; for one series to contain a number in position x, the other series will always contain Nan

Comment: A.fillna(B) or  A.add(B,fill_value=0)

Comment: @YOBEN_S thanks a lot that did it